# ScalaTest in Intellij does not print out console messages

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I am running Spark tests that use ScalaTest. They are very chatty on the command line using the following command (as an aside the -Dtest= is apparently ignored - all core tests are being run..):

```
 mvn -Pyarn -Phive test -pl core -Dtest=org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerSuite
```

There are thousands of lines of output, here is a taste:

```
7:03:30.251 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished TID 4417 in 23 ms on localhost (progress: 4/4)
17:03:30.252 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 38.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17:03:30.252 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Completed ResultTask(38, 3)
17:03:30.252 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stage 38 (apply at Transformer.scala:22) finished in 0.050 s
17:03:30.288 INFO org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://localhost:4041
17:03:30.289 INFO org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
```

However in IJ only tests Pass/Fail are printed out.  So how to view the same chatty INFO level output as on command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log4j.properties was not on the classpath. The way I fixed this:

(a) create a log4j.properties inside the test/**resources** folder

(b) the Following log4j.properties file worked for me:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the file bagel/target/unit-tests.log
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Ignore messages below warning level from Jetty, because it's a bit verbose
# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
```